# Page is not found but it is accessible actually

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am using wordpress theme [Division](http://billykids-lab.net/division/) which ships with [Jackbox](http://codecanyon.net/item/jackbox-responsive-lightbox/3078222).

The issue is the social icons in [this link](http://www.capuletsgarden.com.au/gallery-large-metro-no-gutter/#/gallery_562/2) display as a white box, instead they should display a collection of social icons. If you open up a console, you will find an error that a link cannot be found. The strange thing is that if I delete all parameters excepts those associated with social icons like the following link.

http://www.capuletsgarden.com.au/wp-content/themes/division/jackbox/modules/jackbox_social.php?twitter=0&google=1&facebook=1&pinterest=1

it can show the social icons perfectly. Why can different parameters of a link make it inaccessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for the `poster` is causing an `404`:

http://billykids-lab.net/division/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/photodune-515704-sunrise-s.jpg

which then prevents the social buttons from loading:

The include contains the following link:

```
http://www.capuletsgarden.com.au/wp-content/themes/division/jackbox/modules/jackbox_social.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.capuletsgarden.com.au%2Fgallery-large-metro-no-gutter%2F%23%2Fgallery_562%2F2&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fbillykids-lab.net%2Fdivision%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F06%2Fphotodune-515704-sunrise-s.jpg&title=Ocena%2520sunset&twitter=0&google=1&facebook=1&pinterest=1
```

Within that, there are several sub-urls as parameter, like `url=...` and `poster=...`. The latter  one causes a `404`. This then stops al the rest from being executed.

Comment: could you explain it a bit more?